# Wavefunction for Anti-Pfaffian state

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, quantum-hall-effect, topological-phase

What is the most general form of a wavefunction for anti-Pfaffian in variables $\{z_i\}$ which represent the positions of electrons on a two dimensional plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic procedure to obtain the particle-hole conjugate of a quantum Hall wavefunction is described in http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.29.6012. It is not clear whether this is the most "general" form. But even for the Pfaffian state, we do not know the most general form either.